How can I display the last data label of a series within a line chart in .net with Epplus?
I have a line chart in an Excel document. I need to display the last data label of a data series, my code looks like this:
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

            // Add headers for the data
            worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Date";
            worksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Value";

            // Define the start and end dates
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 1);
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1);

            // Add records for each day between the start and end dates
            int row = 2;
            for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {
                var r = new Random();
                worksheet.Cells[$"A{row}"].Value = date; // Date
                worksheet.Cells[$"A{row}"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd-mmm-yy";

                worksheet.Cells[$"B{row}"].Value = r.NextDouble(); // Value
                row++;
            }

            // Add a line chart
            var chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("lineChart", eChartType.Line) as ExcelLineChart;
            chart.Title.Text = "Sample Line Chart";
            chart.SetPosition(1, 0, 3, 0);
            chart.SetSize(1200, 600);

            // Add the main series to the chart
            var series = chart.Series.Add(worksheet.Cells[$"B2:B{row - 1}"], worksheet.Cells[$"A2:A{row - 1}"]);
            series.Header = "Series 1";

            // Displays the series DataLabels.
            series.DataLabel.ShowValue = true;
            series.DataLabel.Font.Size = 12;
            series.DataLabel.Position = eLabelPosition.Top;

            // Save the package
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "SampleData.xlsx");
            var fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
            package.SaveAs(fi);

            Console.WriteLine($"Data and chart created successfully at: {filePath}");
        }
    }
}

Result of this code:

I need to show only the last value in the series.

I found an example applied in VB.

Please [edit] your question and indicate which part of the question you link to is essential for you. Did some code there show what you want, but in VB, and could it not be used in C#? If so, which code?
